# Use Style From XAML In C#

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, styles, listboxitem

I have an style in my `Window.Resources` that i want to use in my behind code:

XAML :

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle1" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

C# :

```
ListBoxItem lbi = new ListBoxItem();
lbi.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["ListBoxItemStyle1"];
.
.
.
MyListBox.Items.Add(lbi);
```

But this is not working, any solution?

Comment: This is a really bad idea. When you create WPF UI elements in C#, you're essentially fighting the framework, and the framework always wins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `FindResource` or `TryFindResource` method, the `Style` will be found regardless of whether you define it in the window or globally:

```
lbi.Style = TryFindResource("ListBoxItemStyle1") as Style;
```